# Angular 2 , Observable updates adding an item, but not deleting

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

thanks for reading this question.

Anyway, I've create a service which handles lists of items(which have name and price) This service returns an observable , to which my ListComponent subscribes.

The weird thing is ,that when I add an item , the subscribe works and the ListComponent List is updated, when I delete an item, the subscribe doesn't work, it doesn't send any errors.

ListComponent:

```
    export class ListComponent {


  listItems: ListItem[];
  itemName: string;
  itemPrice: number;
  constructor(private listService: ListItemService){
     this.listService.getItems().subscribe((res) => {
      this.listItems=res;
    },
       (error)=>{
       console.log(error);
       })
  }
  public addNewItem(itemName:string,itemPrice:number):void{
    this.listService.create(itemName,itemPrice);
  }
  public deleteItem(itemName:string){
    this.listService.delete(itemName);
  }

}
```

ListService:

```
  @Injectable()
export class ListItemService {

  private listItems:ListItem[] = [];
  private listObservable: Observable<ListItem[]>;


  constructor() {
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item1",100));
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item2",200));
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item3",300));
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item4",400));

    this.listObservable = Observable.of(this.listItems);
  }
  getItems(): Observable<ListItem[]> {
    return this.listObservable;

  }
  getItemById(name: String): Promise<ListItem> {
    return new Promise((resolve) =>{
      resolve(this.getListItemByName(name));
    })
  }
  delete(name: String): Promise<ListItem[]> {
   let item = new ListItem(name,0);
   this.listItems = this.listItems.filter((item:ListItem)=>item.name !== name);
   return new Promise((res)=>{
     res(item);
   })
  }
  create(name: string, price:number): Promise<ListItem> {
    let item: ListItem = new ListItem(name,price);
    this.listItems.push(item);
    return new Promise((res)=>{
      res(item);
    })
  }}
```

Thanks for reading (and hopefully helping)

Comment: Please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your observable isn't doing anything except getting the initial `listItems` array from the service. The observable is never being fired after that point. You should be using a Subject for this.

Anyway, the reason for your problem is that when you add, you're mutating `listItems` (by calling `push`). The subscriber is not called. The component only sees this change because it is still pointing to the original `listItems` array object.

When you remove, you're creating a new `listItems` array in the service rather than mutating it. The component is still looking at the old `listItems` array so it doesn't see that change.

What you should be doing instead is something like this:

```
@Injectable()
export class ListItemService {
  private listItems: ListItem[] = [];
  private listSubject = new Subject<ListItem[]>();
  private listObservable = this.listSubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item1",100));
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item2",200));
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item3",300));
    this.listItems.push(new ListItem("item4",400));
  }
  getItems(): Observable<ListItem[]> {
    return this.listObservable;
  }
  delete(name: String): Promise<ListItem[]> {
   let item = new ListItem(name,0);
   this.listItems = this.listItems.filter((item:ListItem)=>item.name !== name);
   this.listSubject.next(this.listItems);
  }
  create(name: string, price:number): Promise<ListItem> {
    let item: ListItem = new ListItem(name,price);
    this.listItems = [...this.listItems, item]; // better not to mutate
    this.listSubject.next(this.listItems);
  }}
```